# Drupal 7 book-module: how to add tables and remove tabs?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm new to Drupal and trying to create a book to be used for my site's FAQ.

I have 2 simple questions please:

1. How can you get rid of the tabs listing every single page of my book or at least reduce the number of shown tabs to 3-4, so that there is no "stack overflow" as shown in the screenshot below?

   [image]

   I don't see these "tabs" anywhere in Home >> Administration >> Structure.
2. In one book page I need to create a table. How could I enable tables (HTML-tables?) in book pages please?

   I go to Home >> Administration >> Content >> Books and then?

   Or should I go to Home >> Administration >> Structure, then Book page - edit and then?

   [image]

I'm reading a lot of Drupal docs, but for some questions like these ones you just need someone in person to answer them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you haven't added them yourself?

When creating content, there is a "Provide a menu link" checkbox in the Menu settings. If that is checked, then you will get these links.

If you don't want them, just uncheck that checkbox or remove them at admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu

Comment: That is correct, I've checked the check box for each book page, to add them to the Main Menu. And I'm showing the Main Menu in the Footer first column - as you can see at the left-bottom corner of my screenshots.

Is there maybe a way to get rid of the tabs, but keep the Main Menu in the left-bottom corner?

Comment: The tabs *are* the main menu. If you don't want that, disable it in your theme. Or use a different menu for your book items.

Answer (score 0):

I've found how to get rid of the tabs: go to Home >> Administration >> Sctructure >> Menus, then Settings tab and select "No Main Links" (to get rid of the tabs) and "No Secondary Links" (to get rid of links in the top-right corner) there.

[image]

I've also submitted [a minor bug](http://drupal.org/node/1080026) there.